# Can a silverlight control have both a DataTemplate and a ControlTemplate at once?

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0, controls, controltemplate

I suspect that the ContentControl which have a property of ContentTemplate is either a DataTemplate or a ControlTemplate depending on what each of derived silverlight control has declared it in its class.

If yes, how can I customize both of them for the same control at once?

e.g. A ListBoxItem is a ContentControl, I can set its ContentTemplate to a DataTemplate declaratively inline. Can I set a custom ControlTemplate for it inline? or A ControlTemplate can only be set separately?

Comment: The `ContentTemplate` is always a `DataTemplate` as it templates the content, which can be data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every control has a `ControlTemplate` which defines what the control looks like. A control can have multiple `DataTemplates` depending on how it deals with data, a `ContentControl` usually only has `Content` which can be templated via a `ContentTemplate`. Some headered control may also have a data template property to template the header, it all depends on the control you are using.

Comment: I was still editing my question before looking at your reply. Please see the updated question, specially the one in the example.

Comment: @puretechy: What do you mean by "inline"? The properties don't behave any different from each other.

Comment: I will update my question in few hours after doing my own study.